# Filter CriteriaQuery JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa

I am making an application with Java 1.6, Jsf 2.0, JPA 2.0, Primefaces 5.3 over a WebLogic server 10.3.6

I require to implement the lazy datatables burden for certain modules and I could not make the filter work.

This is the load method:

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
    SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    //Criteria Query
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.ejbUtils.getEntityManagerPrivate().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);

    //From
    Root<T> from = cq.from(entityClass);

    //Sort
    if(sortField != null){
        if(sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING){
            cq.orderBy(cb.asc(from.get(sortField)));
        }else{
            cq.orderBy(cb.desc(from.get(sortField)));
        }
    }

    //Filters
    if(!filters.isEmpty()){

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        for (Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

            String filterProperty = it.next();
            Object filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);                   
            Expression<String> literal = cb.upper(cb.literal((String)filterProperty.toUpperCase()));

            predicates.add(cb.like(literal, String.valueOf("%" + filterValue + "%").toUpperCase()));

        }               
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));             
    }   

    Query q = this.ejbUtils.getEntityManagerPrivate().createQuery(cq);

    list = q
            .setFirstResult(first)
            .setMaxResults(pageSize)
            .getResultList();

    this.setRowCount(this.ejbUtils.count());

    return list;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

And I look at the log EclipseLink and throws me this

[EL Fine]: 2016-07-15 11:15:35.415--ServerSession(1294563329)--Connection(1645363733)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '21' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT * FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS / a., ROWNUM rnum FROM (SELECT ID AS a1, ACTION AS a2, ACTIVA AS a3, FECHA_CREACION AS a4, FECHA_MODIFICACION AS a5, NOMBRE AS a6, USUARIO_CREACION AS a7, USUARIO_MODIFICACION AS a8, ID_PADRE AS a9 FROM SE_OPCIONES WHERE UPPER(?) LIKE ?) a WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) WHERE rnum > ? bind => [NOMBRE, %ROL%, 10, 0]

Then when I enter a filter in the datatable never brings results.

Comment: several things: I don't see an error and does the query work from a plain java class with a main (or a unit test)

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed, replacing

```
predicates.add(cb.like(literal, String.valueOf("%" + filterValue + "%").toUpperCase()));
```

by

```
predicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(from.get(filterProperty).as(String.class)), String.valueOf("%" + filterValue + "%").toUpperCase()));
```